# Javascript prototype inheritance issue

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with prototype inheritance and I can't find out why it's not working properly.

The snippet is this:

```
function Field(newKey, val) {
    this.key = newKey || "";
    this.value = val || "";
}

Field.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return this.value === undefined || this.value === null || this.value === "";
};

function DoubleField(newKey, val) {
    this.base = Field;
    this.base(newKey, val);
}
DoubleField.prototype = new Field();
DoubleField.prototype.constructor = DoubleField;

function IntegerField(newKey, val) {
    this.base = DoubleField;
    this.base(newKey, val);
}
IntegerField.prototype = new DoubleField();
IntegerField.prototype.constructor = IntegerField;

var f = new Field('keyfield', 'valField');
var d = new DoubleField('keydouble', 'valDouble');
var i = new IntegerField('keyinteger');

var res = f.isEmtpy();
```

The call to f.isEmpty is failing? Why? Calls to d.isEmpty or i.isEmpty work just fine as expected.

I cannot realize what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Failing" ***how***? (Note that it's misspelled, you have `var res = f.isEmtpy();` but it should be `var res = f.isEmpty();`)

Comment: All of a sudden, compilation errors seem awesome!

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: That's what lint tools are for, no question.

Comment: Facetious! Thanks for the word! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the last line of code:

```
var res = f.isEmtpy();//That's what you wrote
```

The correct is:

```
var res = f.isEmpty();
```

Comment: @Calapacho you should use firebug or Chrome inspector to help find your errors. Without proper debugging tools, coding really sucks.

Comment: Damn! I've been looking at the code for an hour not noticing that! I did use firebug but the problem was I wasn't realizing about the typo anyway. Thanks
BTW, using JSLint did helped a lot too!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said *how* it's failing. As I noted in a comment, at the very least there's a typo: `var res = f.isEmtpy();` should be `var res = f.isEmpty();`

But beyond that (which I assume is just a typo in the *question*, not the code), note that this line in your derived constructors:

```
this.base = DoubleField;
```

...will not work as you intend. Consider the case of `IntegerField`. You call `new IntegerField` and it sets `this.base` to `DoubleField` and calls it. But the `DoubleField` constructor then sets `this.base` to `Field`. So you have an `IntegerField` instance with a `base` property pointing to `Field`, not `DoubleField`.

You can't use instance properties to trace lineage. It works for a parent/child situation, but you run into the "grandchild" problem described above.

I recommend using one of the inheritance helper scripts out there. There are several, including my own [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/). These scripts help you build inheritance hierarchies, handling the plumbing for you so you can focus on building whatever it is you're trying to build. We only need them temporarily; JavaScript is getting [syntactic sugar to help with this](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aclasses) in the next version (but of course, it'll be years before we see widespread support of it, once it's actually finalized).

Comment: @t-j-crowder: thanks for the answer, however I want to know what I'm doing instead of using a library that would solve my issues. Besides, I cannot use libraries actually in my code. Policy problems...
BTW, I've been watching a video from Crockford about this and he explains how to solve it with closures. Maybe that would help in my case to solve the grandchild issue. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Comment: @Calapacho: Just reading the Lineage source should help you understand this stuff (although my passion for giving functions *names* may make it a bit trickier to read than necessary; when you get to it, follow the non-named ctor branch of the code). Absolutely pay attention to Crockford, but make your own determinations. He's a smart, informed person, but he has a tendency to state his opinion as fact (his *JavaScript: The Good Parts* does that a fair bit). For straight hierarchies such as yours, you don't need closures. (You may *want* them, for private data etc., but you don't *need* them.)